# How can I get checked recyclerview item in bottomSheet And Pass multiple Checked data by button in bottomSheet

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

Hi I don't know how to upload multiple checked recyclerview item data to firebase.

So I think I have to know which recyclerview item is checked for uploading data to firebase.

But In bottomsheet java file, I don't know How can I get which one is checked.

My scenarios is that, If user check items'checkbox (multiple item check is available) and click done button, Uploading data to firebase.

How can I solve it?

It's my Adapter for recyclerview in bottomsheet

```
public class AdapterPinBottomSheet extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPinBottomSheet.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<ItemBottomSheetFolderList> array;
Context context;
private RecyclerViewClickListener listener;

public AdapterPinBottomSheet(ArrayList<ItemBottomSheetFolderList> array, Context context, RecyclerViewClickListener listener) {
    this.array = array;
    this.context =context;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AdapterPinBottomSheet.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_folderlist_bottomsheet,parent,false);
    return new AdapterPinBottomSheet.ViewHolder(view);
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterPinBottomSheet.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ItemBottomSheetFolderList itemBottomSheetFolderList = array.get(position);
    holder.listFolderName.setText(array.get(position).getFolderName());
    holder.listFolderPinNum.setText(String.valueOf(array.get(position).getFolderPinNum()));
    holder.cbPinFolder.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    holder.cbPinFolder.setChecked(itemBottomSheetFolderList.isSelected());

    holder.cbPinFolder.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            itemBottomSheetFolderList.setSelected(isChecked);
        }
    });

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return array.size();
}

public interface RecyclerViewClickListener{
    void onClick(View v, int position);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView listFolderName;
    TextView listFolderPinNum;
    CheckBox cbPinFolder;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        listFolderName =itemView.findViewById(R.id.listFolderName);
        listFolderPinNum =itemView.findViewById(R.id.listFolderPinNum);
        cbPinFolder =itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbPinFolder);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.onClick(itemView, getAdapterPosition());
        cbPinFolder.performClick();
    }
}

}
```

And This code(in dialog file) is related to recyclerview.

```
public interface BottomSheetListener {
    void onButtonClicked(String text);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        mListener = (BottomSheetListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement BottomSheetListener");
    }
}

private void setFolderOnClickListener(){
    folderListener = new AdapterPinBottomSheet.RecyclerViewClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v, int position) {
            mListener.onButtonClicked("폴더 clicked");
        }
    };
}
```

For understanding I add my UI

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method in your Adapter which you can call on Done click to get the selected list of data. something like below

```
 public ArrayList<ItemBottomSheetFolderList> getSelectedArray() {
        ArrayList<ItemBottomSheetFolderList> selectedArray = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ItemBottomSheetFolderList folderList : array) {
            if (folderList.isSelected()) {
                selectedArray.add(folderList);
            }
        }
        return selectedArray;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm a beginner so I need more advice..! Is it right to add your code in adapter ViewHolder class?  And How can I call this in bottomsheet filre?                    I tried like    ((AdapterPinBottomSheet)folderRecyclerView.getAdapter().getSelectedArray());           But I can't find that method.

Comment: Thank you sir!!! I solved it. I had mistake to putting ). By        ((AdapterPinBottomSheet)folderRecyclerView.getAdapter()).getSelectedArray();            this I solve!